# Coloured Jones polynomial of the mirror image of a multicomponent link

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, knot-link, jones-polynomial, homflypt-polynomial

This question has been reposted from MathStackExchange

It is well understood that the usual Jones polynomial of a knot or link can be related to the Jones polynomial of the mirror image of the knot/link by changing the variable $V_L(t) \to V_L(t^{-1})$. More generally, the HOMFLY-PT polynomial of the mirror image can be obtained by switching from $P_L(l,m) \to P_L(l^{-1},m)$.

So can an equivalent statement be made about the Coloured Jones Polynomial of an arbitrary link, for the same colouring? For a link $L$ and mirror image $L^\star$ is the relation $C^{L}_{N,M,\cdots}(t) = C^{L^\star}_{N,M,\cdots}(t^{-1})$ true? Is there a reference for this?

This does seem to be the case in the [paper](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1172-3.pdf) by Habiro on pages 3 and 4, for the left and right handed trefoil knots as well as the left and right handed Whitehead Links

Comment: I am pretty sure this is true. If it is the proof would to be understanding how taking duals affects the highest weights of your modules, and this should correspond to the inversions you mentioned. However I haven’t thought about this carefully and I’m not sure if exactly the statement you want is written down anywhere.

Comment: Actually you might need to be a little more careful: for a mirror image (not just orientation change) you also need to invert the R matrices and that’s a more complicated change.

Comment: It should be easy to check with the help of the introduction by Murakami https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0126 and in particular the explicit formula 2.2 for R and 2.4 for its inverse.